# trying to load QC11.5 using Neoload but recorded response not stored by neoload

Tags: neoload

I am trying to do a loadtest on QC11.5 application using Neoload, While recording request are being captured but response body not been stored.

```
<<body not stored by Neoload >> Error
```

please help to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Hum... It sounds like a well-known project ;> Here is a summary for the other readers. Hewlett Packard Quality Center 10 or 11 is not a "full" web application. It is kind of local application, installed through Internet Explorer with .cab and .ocx using a HTTP tunnel. The problem to load test it is that the dialog sent by this fat client is fully encrypted. For NeoLoad, an encrypted conversation (over HTTP or HTTPS) is considered as binary and it is not stored in the design. But it is clearly showed in the "Check VU" step. Here we speak about an "alien" encrypting service on top of standard services like SSL, where NeoLoad performs well.

For the readers, to put it in a nutshell, QC cannot be load tested with a network-based approach, like all the majors and professional load testing tools do. Here it is one of the rare situations where a synchronized functional test could be the solution... with hundreds or thousands of desktops.